# Retrieve the parent of a clicked element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a < table > - < tr > - < td > structure. Each < td > includes a < div > with three < span > inside.
I need a function, which returns the clicked < td > every time I click either < td > or any of its elements (< div >, < span >#1, < span >#2, < span >#3).

What I tried is setting z-index property to < td > of higher value than one to < div > and < span > elements. Thus, I tried to "hide" them behind < td >, but it didn't work.

Here's what I've got now:
http://jsbin.com/mocajahalu/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Please, help.

Comment: It's as easy as `$(this).closest('td')`, or in your case `$(e.target).closest('td')` as you're targeting the document

Comment: Right, but I have to use native Javascript only.

Comment: Then you'd have to recreate `closest` in native javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
document.addEventListener('click',function (e) {
   var parentEl = null;

   if (e.target.tagName === "TD") {
     // When user clicks on TD
     parentEl = e.target;
   } else if (e.target.parentElement.tagName === "TD") {
     // When user clicks on any of its child element (The DIVs and SPANs)
     // If user clicks on any child elements
     parentEl = e.target.parentElement;
   }

   // parentEl is the TD element
   alert(parentEl);
   e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Comment: great, just as i commented my answer that you could check nodeName (or tagName) you came up with this at the same time :) - but also here, if your SPAN elements have children, you will have to check parentNode in a loop

Answer (score 0):

try using `parentNode` an attribute of the current DOM node:

```
document.addEventListener('click',function (e) {
  alert('You clicked ' +e.target.parentNode);
  e.preventDefault();
},false);
```

That should do the trick!

To make sure that you have not clicked on the TD element itself you could check:

```
TDnode = e.target;
if (TDnode.nodeName!='TD') TDnode = TDnode.parent;
```

In case your spans could have child elements, you would have to check each parentNode until you have your TD node. If you use `while(TDNode.nodeName!='TD')` you have to make sure to check if parentNode is 'undefined' or not.

Comment: Parent node for TD is TR<TABLE<DOCUMENT
But document.table.tr.td.addEventListener('click',function (e) {
  alert('You clicked ' +e.target);
  e.preventDefault();
},false); doesn't work

Comment: obviously you would want to catch that, since the suggested parentNode is for the child SPAN elements. so you coiuld check if e.target is TD and only if not use parentNode.